# Por que no es obligatorio implementar los métodos de una interfaz en una clase abtracta?

Tags: java, poo, herencia, clase-abstracta, interface

Quizás la pregunta es un poco estúpida, pero aún así quisiera saber el por qué. Por qué si una clase abstracta implementa una interfaz no es obligatorio implementar dichos métodos? Normalmente no mostraría el error de que faltan métodos por implementar, pero en las clases abstractas no sucede esto. Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una clase abstracta es una clase que no se puede instanciar, tienes que crear una clase hija obligatoriamente.

Eso nos permite crear una clase "inacabada":

```
public abstract class MiClaseAbstracta {

    void metodo1(String s) {
        System.out.println("Hola, " + s);
    }

    void abstract metodo2(String s);
}
```

Observa que el método `metodo2` no está implementado (es abstracto), es una tarea pendiente de la clase hija.

De hecho podríamos crear una clase abstracta con todos los métodos abstractos, lo que haría que la diferencia entre una clase abstracta o una interfaz fuera más semántica que funcional.

Por otro lado tienes interfaces, que de manera similar declaran métodos que debes cumplir:

```
public interface OperacionAritmetica {

   void metodo3();

   default int operar(int a, int b) {
       return a+b;
   }
}
```

Aquí ocurre lo contrario que en las clases abstractas, los métodos son por defecto abstractos (no hace falta usar la declaración `abstract`, se asume) pero puedes dar una implementación por defecto, en este caso el método operar.

Si tienes una clase abstracta que cumple esta interfaz, podrías hacer algo como:

```
public abstract class OperacionAbstracta implements OperacionAritmetica {

    void metodo1(String s) {
        System.out.println("Hola, " + s);
    }

    abstract void metodo2(String s);

    abstract void metodo3(); // de la interfaz

}
```

Pero esto **no aporta nada**: el método `metodo3` ya sabemos que tiene que ser implementado por la clase hija para cumplir la interfaz `OperacionAritmetica`; es redundante y añadirlo aquí solo sirve para confundir: ¿tenemos que aplicarlo para cumplir la interfaz o porque la clase padre nos obliga? Cualquier clase que extienda `OperacionAbstracta` también implementará, por herencia, `OperacionAritmetica`, con lo que podemos quitar la necesidad de mencionarlo siquiera en la clase padre.